# Conditional to update field not working properly - Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, string, conditional

I am attempting to update a text field with a shortened version of what is currently there.  Currently, there are values from 1 to 4 with a description of each.  I would like to return only the value.  I tried a few different snippets of code to achieve this.  However, when I run the code, only some of the values change as I would like.  My most current code is:

```
try:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(protectTable, "gap_stat") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            for n in row[0].split():
                if n[0] == "1":
                    row[0] = "1"
                elif n[0] == "2":
                    row[0] = "2"
                elif n[0] == "3":
                    row[0] = "3"
                elif n[0] == "4":
                    row[0] = "4"
                else:
                    pass
            cursor.updateRow(row)
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

Here is an example of the result where some of the values change and some do not:

[image]

Comment: When presenting any code snippet here I think it is best to remove try/except statements because they can mask the error messages that might otherwise help you and us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to keep only the first character of the field value, this is much simpler and would work just fine:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(protectTable, "gap_stat") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if not row[0] is None:
            print row[0]
            row[0] = row[0][0]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you for the more concise method - it's much cleaner.  However, I'm still having the same issue in that it is not changing some of the values.

Comment: Do you have a subtype or domain on that field?

Comment: There is not a subtype or domain on that field.

Comment: What if you remove the try - except statements - do you get an error message?

Comment: If I run without the try-except statement I get: TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' ... I assume this is in response to the null values for some of the records.

Comment: Well I've modified the code to exclude those empty values. What do you get now? Please also print each field value so we can try to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Create new text field and apply field calculation with python format like.
`"!gap_stat!"[:1]`

It will take just the first character of the field Gap_Stat